# Advanced Number Pattern

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, numbers

Given a Number N, Print the following pattern.

Input Format

The input contains a number N

Constraints

1 < N < 100

Output Format

The required pattern
for input 5 is

```
1 
2 9 
3 8 10 
4 7 11 14 
5 6 12 13 15
```

and for input 3 is

```
1 
2 5 
3 4 6
```

this is the code i have tried .. but the results are not the same

```
#include<stdio.h>
void pattern(int n)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        int k = i;
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",k);
            k =  n - j + k;

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main()
{

    int n = 5;
    pattern(n);
    return 0;
}
```

this is the result of the above code

```
1                                                                                                                                             
2 6                                                                                                                                           
3 7 10                                                                                                                                        
4 8 11 13                                                                                                                                     
5 9 12 14 15
```

How should I modify the above code to get the Expected Output?

Comment: The required pattern structure is not clear, add newline characters for better clarity.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, and not an easy one.  I think you're going to have to have an extra variable, as you move left to right across each row, keeping track of even, odd, even, odd.  In the "even" columns you do what you're already doing, but in the "odd" columns, you have to somehow flip things around so that you count backwards, from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, and not an easy one.  I'm not going to write a program to solve it (in part because I'm too lazy), but I can describe how I would solve it.

You already have an outer loop `for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)` which counts down the rows, and an inner loop `for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)` which counts across the columns.  Those are both fine.

Inside the inner loop I would test `if(j % 2 == 1)`.  If `j % 2` is 1 we're in an odd-numbered column, and we want to count down the column.  But if `j % 2` is 0, we're in an even column, and we have to do it the other way.

First I would have a variable which is the number that's supposed to be at the top of the column (1, 9, 10, 14, or 15 in the n=5 case).  I'd have to compute that number two different ways, one for the "odd" columns and one for the "even".

And then I'd use that number as a base to count down the odd columns, and up the evens.  Specifically: I'd add `i` to it in the odd columns, but subtract `i` in the even columns.  But actually that's not quite right, because `i` is not 1 at the top of columns other than 1, so what I'd actually have to add or subtract would be some function of `i` and `j`.  But I think you can work this out.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my three cents.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const unsigned int UPPER_LIMIT = 100;

        printf( "Enter a non-negative number no greater than %u (0 - exit): ",
                UPPER_LIMIT );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        if ( !( n < UPPER_LIMIT ) ) n = UPPER_LIMIT - 1;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ )
            {

                unsigned int value = j % 2 == 0
                    ? i + 1 + j * n - j * ( j + 1 ) / 2
                    : ( j + 1 ) * n - j * ( j + 1 ) / 2 - i + j;

                printf( "%2u ",  value );               
            }

            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the following way

```
Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 10

 1 
 2 19 
 3 18 20 
 4 17 21 34 
 5 16 22 33 35 
 6 15 23 32 36 45 
 7 14 24 31 37 44 46 
 8 13 25 30 38 43 47 52 
 9 12 26 29 39 42 48 51 53 
10 11 27 28 40 41 49 50 54 55 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 9

 1 
 2 17 
 3 16 18 
 4 15 19 30 
 5 14 20 29 31 
 6 13 21 28 32 39 
 7 12 22 27 33 38 40 
 8 11 23 26 34 37 41 44 
 9 10 24 25 35 36 42 43 45 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 8

 1 
 2 15 
 3 14 16 
 4 13 17 26 
 5 12 18 25 27 
 6 11 19 24 28 33 
 7 10 20 23 29 32 34 
 8  9 21 22 30 31 35 36 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 7

 1 
 2 13 
 3 12 14 
 4 11 15 22 
 5 10 16 21 23 
 6  9 17 20 24 27 
 7  8 18 19 25 26 28 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 6

 1 
 2 11 
 3 10 12 
 4  9 13 18 
 5  8 14 17 19 
 6  7 15 16 20 21 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 5

 1 
 2  9 
 3  8 10 
 4  7 11 14 
 5  6 12 13 15 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 4

 1 
 2  7 
 3  6  8 
 4  5  9 10 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 3

 1 
 2  5 
 3  4  6 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 2

 1 
 2  3 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 1

 1 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 0
```

Or using the recursive approach of calculating the output value the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        const unsigned int UPPER_LIMIT = 100;

        printf( "Enter a non-negative number no greater than %u (0 - exit): ",
                UPPER_LIMIT );

        unsigned int n;

        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;

        if ( !( n < UPPER_LIMIT ) ) n = UPPER_LIMIT - 1;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            unsigned int value = i + 1; 
            for ( unsigned int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ )
            {
                printf( "%2u ",  value );
                value += j % 2 == 0 ? 2 * ( n - i ) - 1 : 2 * ( i - j  ); 
            }

            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For example its output for the entered number equal to 10 looks like

```
Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 10

 1 
 2 19 
 3 18 20 
 4 17 21 34 
 5 16 22 33 35 
 6 15 23 32 36 45 
 7 14 24 31 37 44 46 
 8 13 25 30 38 43 47 52 
 9 12 26 29 39 42 48 51 53 
10 11 27 28 40 41 49 50 54 55 

Enter a non-negative number no greater than 100 (0 - exit): 0
```